# Is the source of jxbrowser available on a git repo?

Tags: jxbrowser

https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

I can not find the source code of jxbrowser on a git repo. Is there a public git repo of jxbrowser source code (with all the revision history)?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser is a proprietary commercial library. Therefore, they don't expose their code to the public. You can consider using free alternatives:

- JCEF. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src

  These guys are based on CEF, a very powerful framework. But it's notoriously harder to use. But it's powerful and open source.
- JavaFX WebView.

  This is a web component, a part of JavaFX. It's much simpler and lighter than both JxBrowser and JCEF. It's not as functional, but very easy to use. If you need to show simple pages in your app, that's your choice.

Comment: but currently there's no jcef binary spread over the internet. We must build it from source .... sigh :(

Comment: Yes. It's not that hard though, I followed their instructions and it worked smoothly. The good this is that you won't need to build CEF, it's already done. The only thing is that their build process produces class files, not JARs. There you'll need to do some scripting.